# Javascript eventListener: create a different sound for each element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, higher-order-functions

I have a folder of 7 sounds.  I am trying to assign a different sound to be played when each of seven buttons is clicked.

However, instead all buttons are getting assigned the last sound in my folder.  Why is this happening?

```
var soundFiles = ["crash", "kick-bass", "snare", "tom-1",
                  "tom-2", "tom-3", "tom-4"];


for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("button").length; i++) {
  var filename = "sounds/" + soundFiles[i] + ".mp3";
  console.log(filename); // prints each filename
  document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    playSound(filename)
  });

}

  function playSound(file) {
    console.log("file = " + file); // only prints the last filename: "sounds/tom-4.mp3"
    var audio = new Audio(file);
    audio.play();
  }
```

Comment: I just learned how to fix this issue by using `bind`.  Inside my for loop I now have the line `document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", playSound.bind(null, filename));`  and the issue is resolved.

Comment: [It is perfectly valid to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Though in this case, the question is apparently a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you Boaz!  You're right... because this question has been marked a duplicate, I don't have the option to answer.  I will keep this in mind for next time.